# Disable TIME_WAIT with boost sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

## TL;DR

I see that my sockets are in `TIME_WAIT` with the `ss` tool in Ubuntu `1804`, but I can't find in the docs for boost sockets or on SO how to set the time delay to `0` such that the socket immediately closes (or better yet, set it to an arbitrarily small value for my application.

I am writing a socket application with Boost asio. Both the client and the server are using boost sockets. I see that, when the client sends a shutdown connection command: `mysocket.shutdown( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error_code);`, and my client C++ application closes down a 2 seconds later, I get `TIME_WAIT` on the output of `ss -ap | grep application_port`. I have been looking around SO and the internet looking for ways to *set* `TIME_WAIT` with Boost C++, but instead, I keep finding questions for *why* a `TIME_WAIT` happens.
Here are some:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666740/receive-data-on-socket-in-time-wait-state
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006324/time-wait-with-boost-asio
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528798/closing-socket-cause-time-wait-pending-state
```

If I am interpreting the internet correctly (and the TCP protocol), the reason why TIME_WAIT happens is because the server connection is waiting for an ACK to allow for the socket conn to die, while the client-side socket has already died.

The question, again:

## Is there a way to set the TIME_WAIT delay option locally for a C++ executable using Boost sockets? If so, how?

Comment: You don't want to do this. The way to avoid the TIME_WAIT, if it is a problem, which it isn't, is to ensure that you are the end that receives the first close. In other words if you're a server have the client close the socket, and have the server react to that close by closing, with a read timeout of course to catch rogue clients. You want the TIME_WAIT states to accumulate at the clients, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SO_LINGER option should help: here's the discussion about it:
[TCP option SO_LINGER (zero) - when it's required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required)

Boost has api for this reason so you can play around with changing linger to 0:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::asio::socket_base::linger option(true, 30);
socket.set_option(option);
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/linger.html

Anyway, it's good to make sure if you really really have to do that. In case if you have a large number of sockets in TIME_WAIT it most probably means that the client site did not close connection gently. So if you can modify the client code, you can consider it as a first option. Here's nice explanation about how to gently finish the communication on TCP socket (it's not about boost but the logic is the same) [Properly close a TCP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872988/properly-close-a-tcp-socket)

Most probably you are not closing the socket. The shutdown operation only informs that peer that there will be no more data to read. So most probably you have to:
- call shutdown
- make sure there's nothng more to read
- close the socket

Comment: It doesn't mean that at all. It merely means that you closed the socket before the peer.